# UIViewAnimation plays instantly, delay is ignored

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a simple UIViewAnimation that is called once my view is loaded.
However no matter what I place as the value for delay, it is ignored and the animation plays instantly.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:100.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(faceRight:finished:context:)];
_chooseLabelContainer.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x, 0 - _chooseLabelContainer.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**Update:** As a test I've mangeled this scenario and below the non-delayed animation happens instantly, but the one within the dispatch queue animates overtime as expected!
    UIView* objectToAnimate = self.hudController->_chooseLabelContainer;

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        NSLog(@"Start Dispatch %@", NSStringFromCGPoint( objectToAnimate.center ) );
        objectToAnimate.center = CGPointMake(objectToAnimate.center.x, objectToAnimate.center.y+90);
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        NSLog(@"Done Dispatch");
    }];


});

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    NSLog(@"Start %@", NSStringFromCGPoint( objectToAnimate.center ) );
    objectToAnimate.center = CGPointMake( objectToAnimate.center.x, objectToAnimate.center.y+30);
}completion:^(BOOL done){
    NSLog(@"Done");
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not solve your problem, but as of iOS 4 Apple recommends you use UIView animation blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:100.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    _chooseLabelContainer.frame = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x, 0 - _chooseLabelContainer.frame.size.height);
}completion:^(BOOL done){
    [self faceRight:finished:context]; //will of course generate errors since I don't know what arguments to pass.
}];
```

Comment: Same problem occurs :( - I had that originally, but simply switched to 'old way' during the debugging process.

Comment: After the transition of this view controller, on the viewDidAppear function

Comment: Another thing to note, is that the animation does not animate, it instantly places the object in place. For debugging i've also placed the above code in touch handler - and the specified view jumps to the new position whenever I tap

Comment: @1dayitwillmake Originally your code included `_chooseLabelContainer.frame` and now I see you've edited it to `_chooseLabelContainer.center`. If you're still using .frame in your code, sending a `CGPoint` to `CGRect` could be causing this.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo from cmd+z before I pasted. If it matters, I have a GLView living simultaneously with the behind this view.